# OCaml - Functions on floats are not working

Tags: floating-point, ocaml

I'm writing some simple operations on floating-point numbers.
But when I use some of the built-in float functions like

```
floor 3.2;;
```

I get this error:

```
This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type
         [ `Deprecated_use__Float__round_down ]
```

What is going wrong here?

I'm on version 4.02.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a `Core` "replacement" for the stdlib function `floor`. Opening `Core` shadows the usual `floor` with a function that has a cute type that that is meant to suggest that the user should pick another function.

You can either follow the suggestion and use `Float.round_down` or get your hands on the original binding and use that.